# Atmel maxtouch touchscreen not showing in xinput list

Tags: linux, touchscreen, xorg

I'm having terrible trouble trying to get my Debian 7 system to recognise my touchscreen. It shows in dmesg that it's there, as follows:

[    2.519893] usb 1-4: Product: Atmel maXTouch Digitizer

[    2.519895] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Atmel

[    2.534210] generic-usb 0003:03EB:8411.0003: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input1

But I'm pretty sure it should say something more input device specific like "config/udev: Adding input device Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer (/dev/input/event*)... and it's not showing in xinput --list either :-(

Does anyone know what I can do to get it to install?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Apparently Atmel touchscreens aren't supported in kernels earlier than 3.9.7, so you'll need to upgrade in case you're running wheezy stable, as I was. After I installed the new kernel, touchscreen "just worked", although I haven't got multitouch functionality working yet.

Comment: were you able to get multitouch working?